# Bash command argument security

Tags: password-management, secret-sharing

Suppose I want to call a program that takes in a username and password to start. What are the risks with calling the program like `./prog --user 'User' --password 'Password'` other than the obvious leak of a user looking over your shoulder?. Is there a safer way to pass in the password?

Comment: Which OS and from the desktop or from a VT? You're vulnerable to a lot of attacks if you have malware running on the same host.

Comment: Have a look the answers in this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3830823/2805324. I found the memory overwrite one especially cunning.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

There's a few ways to pass the password to the program without typing it:

1. Use `read` and a variable

   ```
   read -s password ; ./prog --user 'User' --password "$password"
   ```

   You will have to type the password before executing the program.
2. Use redirection

   Put the password on `password.txt` and execute the program:

   ```
   ./prog --user 'User' --password `cat password.txt`
   ```

Note that even if those methods will conceal the password during the typing, anybody executing a `ps xua | grep prog` will be able to see the password anyway.

If you can change the program to read the password from `stdin` or reading a environment variable, it would make easier to conceal the password. In this case, those methods would work.

Comment: Using the environment is essentially just as bad as a command line argument (try `ps aex` on Linux for instance).

Comment: Both using a variable or substitution on the command line *almost certainly* expose it to other users via `ps` (and/or `/proc`), the shell expands them first. Try it and see: `echo 60 > password.txt; sleep $(cat password.txt) & ps -fp $!`

Answer (score 12):

On most Unix systems the command line is visible to all users, via the ps command. This may not matter greatly if you're on a single-user system, but this is the reason that this approach is generally labelled as insecure. For example: [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-security-user.html).

A better alternative is to store the password in a file, which avoids this leak. You need to make sure the permissions on the file are appropriate. The link I provided explains how to do this for MySQL. A lot of other software support this in some way.

Comment: Re: "the command line is visible to all users": It's not the command line *per se* that's visible, but rather, the arguments to the program. For example, your answer makes it sound like you could store the password in a file named `password_file` and then write `./prog --user 'User' --password "$(cat password_file)"`; but in fact, that would still have the same problem.

Comment: See also https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html#PASS_PHRASE_ARGUMENTS for OpenSSL's take on this.

Answer (score 2):

Make the program read the password itself.

You could use getpass(3) or similar if you are developing in a low-level language. For a shell script you can use read (as it is a builtin, there's no leaking in command arguments).

Also note that if you pass the credentials from somewhere else (such as running that command on a web server, filling the username and password from what was passed by a client), it needs proper quoting, so for instance a password of '`whoami`' doesn't result on remote code execution.